# How do you analyze this matrix to find its determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How do I apply the theorems regarding the determinant of matrix when that matrix is multiplied by a scalar?[image]

Comment: Do you know what row operations do to the determinant?

Comment: Yes, though I'm not really sure about this one since r1, r2, and r3 are being multiplied by 3, -2, and 6 respectively. At the moment can only understand it when lets say r1, r2, and r3 are being multiplied by 2 for example.

Comment: Take it one row at a time. What happens to the determinant if all we do is multiplying the first row by $3$? Or cheat: Pretend that your matrix is $2I$ (or some other, very simple determinant-8 matrix), and use that in your claculations.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you, I understand it now. So I'm really just suppose to multiply the determinant 8 by all the scalars that were multiplied with each of the row to get -288 correct?

Comment: @Alkahest That's what I got too.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your first matrix $A = (A_{i,j})_{1\leqslant i,j \leqslant 3}$ and your second matrix $B = (B_{i,j})_{1\leqslant i,j \leqslant 3}$.

$\operatorname{det}(B) = \sum_{\sigma \in \mathcal{S}_3} sgn(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^3  B_{i,\sigma(i)}$, where $\mathcal{S}_3$ is the group of all permutations of $\{1;2;3\}$ and $sgn(\sigma)$ is the signature of $\sigma$.
For all $1\leqslant j \leqslant 3$, we have that $B_{1,j} = 3 A_{1,j}$, $B_{2,j} = -2 A_{2,j}$ and $B_{3,j} = 6 A_{3,j}$. Hence, for any $\sigma \in \mathcal{S}_3$, we get
$$\prod_{i=1}^3  B_{i,\sigma(i)} = 3\cdot(-2)\cdot 6 \cdot \prod_{i=1}^3  A_{i,\sigma(i)} = -36 \cdot \prod_{i=1}^3  A_{i,\sigma(i)} $$
All in all, we get $\boxed{\operatorname{det}(B) = -36\cdot \operatorname{det}(A)}$.